# How to remap and add extra property in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter and wanted to try to remap the data from firestore.

The data from firestore

```
[
{name:"john",age:12},
{name:"wick",age:12},
]
```

Expected Result

```
[
  {name:"john",age:12,id:xxx},
    {name:"wick",age:12,id:xxx},
]
```

Is this possible to add new property like this? I try to use map but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it it possible, you need to iterate over it so you can access each item, then use the spread operator `...`, or the `addAll` method of the `Map`:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {"name": "john", "age": 12},
    {"name": "wick", "age": 12},
  ];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> newList = actionOn(list);

  print(newList);
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> actionOn(List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) {
  return list.map((Map<String, dynamic> elem) {
    return {...elem, "age": 12};
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: Alright understood sir, what if the error shown : This literal must be either a map or a set, but the elements don't have enough information for type inference to work.
Try adding type arguments to the literal (one for sets, two for maps). ? @Gwhyyy

Comment: I will edit the answer